# To make gcc 4.8.1 support the new "auto" feature in c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I use the gcc 4.8.1 compiler to compile my code, which use the new c++11 feature of **auto**. It is supposed that the **auto** keyword would automatically infer the data type. However, the compiler throw out an error :

```
   *** does not name a type
```

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string str="If you want to do it, try your best.";
    cout<<str<<endl;
    for(auto i:str){             //<-error here
        cout<<i<<endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

And the error is :

```
'i' does not name a type.....(of course there are some error message following)
```

And my compiler version is:`gcc version 4.8.1(in MingW)`

According to the gcc document, this version of gcc have already supported c++11,
so why would this happen?

Comment: compile with -std=c++11 flag

Comment: Are you compiling with `-std=c++11`?

Comment: By adding `-std=c++11` to the command line when you run g++

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile with the `-std=c++11` flag

e.g:

```
gcc somefile.c -std=c++11
```

Comment: Thanks. I used to use the IDE to program and don't know much about that .

Comment: There is probably an option in your IDE to add compiler flags when compiling your code, it could be useful to look it up